# Test in Web Chat not working with the app service

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, botframework

I've deployed a bot framework chatbot as an app service. Everything is working fine. I was able to connect it bot framework emulator using ngrok. But when I'm trying to use the test in the web chat option it shows nothing. What causing this problem? Do I need to configure tunneling on azure chat bot as well?

I have configured `appsettings.json` by providing the required values. And I have created a secret key using key vault and added as the password as well.

Deployment method:
Created an app service and deployed directly from the vs code.

Update: I have checked the logs on the azure bot service.It shows the error as **There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code InternalServerError.**

Comment: How you have deployed your App to azure ?

Comment: Yes, BTW I have used .net framework version to develop the bot.

Comment: Did you set your messaging endpoint in your Azure Bot resource to the URL of the Azure App Service?

Comment: @AP01 Yes I did

Comment: You'll need to provide the specific steps you took. There are plenty of steps where you could have made a mistake.

Comment: First, check the Microsoft app id and password in azure configuration settings and in your app settings in the application. if both are correct then validate any environmental variable ( dev, prod, etc ) in app settings in azure configuration.

Answer (score 1):

- I have deployed a sample Weather bot to azure using below steps
- This worked in my local system as below.

[image: entestrong textr image description here]

- Now **we need** to deploy from the **Bot to the Azure portal. To do this,** follow **these steps:**
- On the left corner -> Click **Publish** and select **manage profile** as below.

[image]

- Select **Add new** as below.

[image]

- Click on **Crate new resource** and then click on **Next** as below.

[image]

- Give all the **details** as below and click on **Next**.

[image]

[image]

- After creating the manage profile and select the name of the app which you have created in the above steps as below.

[image]

- Select the app you have created and select the bot as below and click on **publish selected bots**.

[image]

- After deploying the Bot App navigate to Bot App which you have deployed in your selected resource Group -> Click on **Test in web Chat** as below.

[image]